# how to set dimensions of SeekBar in android programatically?

Tags: android, seekbar

I have initialized seek bar in Activity Class like this :

```
SeekBar mySeekBar = new SeekBar(this);
```

It is too small how can I set dimentions for It ? 
scale and setScrollBarSize methods didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add it to a ViewGroup, you specify appropriate LayoutParams for it. Try this:

```
viewGroup.addView(mySeekBar, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

If you need to something more complicated depending on the layout, you can create a each layout has a LayoutParams inner class that you can create an instance of and make modifications to, then add the view using

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(...);
/* do stuff with params */
viewGroup.addView(mySeekBar, params);
```